# Elementary OS logout bug

Tags: session

I don't know why, but my ElementaryOS logout, when I open same applications. I just installed the operating system on my computer, update the system normally and then it started to fail. It's my first time with Elementary OS.

Does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Not my first time with eOS, However just came back to it. Same issue with 5.1 seems like any of the system apps when opened just crash me back to the login screen.